# C# My counter does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, counter

Hi can anyone help I am not sure why my counter in my button next is not working sorry about all the other code. I want to build run through data in my database by using a counter. If there is an easier way to do it that will also work.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int iDefualt = 2;
    int iMainCounter = 0;
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=EON;Initial Catalog=DW2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Kapow;Password=Kapow");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();              

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con1.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        //SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from customer_registration where username='" + Session["username"] + "'", con1);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sNavigate(0), con1);
        /SELECT * FROM tblDW2 WHERE [User]='Petrus'
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            txtbxDaywords.Text = (myReader["Dayword"].ToString());
        }
        con1.Close();    
        iMainCounter = iDefualt;
        // "Daywords\t" + "\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
    public string sNavigate(int iNavNum)
    {
        int iNavigate;

        if (iNavNum != 0)
        {
            iNavigate = iNavNum;    
        }
        else
        {                    
            iNavigate = iDefualt;
        }        
        return "SELECT * FROM (SELECT Dayword, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dayword) AS      Rownumber FROM tblDW2 WHERE [User]='Petrus' ) results WHERE results.Rownumber = "+ iNavigate.ToString();
    }    
    protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iMainCounter++;    
        con1.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sNavigate(iMainCounter), con1);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();    
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            txtbxDaywords.Text = (myReader["Dayword"].ToString());
        }
        con1.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to give him private const int type

Comment: You should try to pin down your problem. Prepare a "smallest compilable example" with just the button and the counter.

Comment: private const int won't do, its const, use private static int

Comment: study a bit more how asp.net works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the ASP.NET Page Life cycle when ever you have any variable initialized in any of the events, may it be page load or any other event. that initialization is specific to the user
and will be re-initialized as soon as the event gets fired.

Solution:

If you are looking forward to hold the counter globally (Not specific to a user): Use application variable to hold the counter value

If you are looking forward to hold the counter specific to a user (for specific user through out the application): use Session to hold the counter Value

Please let me know if you would need a sample code so that I can provide.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Incrementer"] == null)
        {
            Session["Incrementer"] = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            int incrementer = Convert.ToInt32(Session["incrementer"].ToString()) + 1;
            Session["incrementer"] = incrementer.ToString();
        }
        Label1.Text = Session["incrementer"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is what I wanted to do. But is there a way to set a default value to the incrementer before it starts counting? For example I want to set in a day counter and every day it moves the default starting point for all the users one day ahead each day? And then I want to set that point as the starting point for the incrementer that they can navigate from that point forwards and backwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't store somewhere your counter it will be resetted after a `PageLoad` or a `PostBack`

[Web page are stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)

you can use [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) o [SessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.ASPX)

anyway if you dont put the counter initilization inside an

```
If(!IsPostBack)
{
    iMainCounter = iDefualt; 
}
```

everytime it will be resetted

Answer (score 0):

In this way you count will be always 2 because you set it in the page load event, and the page load event to check for Ispostback so it will always re initialize to be equal iDefault.
so you should set the iDefault in not post back validation

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   iMainCounter = iDefault;
}
```

Another problem is the `iMainCounter` not set to static, so each transaction will re-initialize it, so use `static int iMainCounter = 0`